# Using envoy without pods (in on pres solution)

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

We are now on our journey to break our monolith (on-prem pkg (rpm/ova)) into services (dockers).

In the process we are evaluation envoy/istio as our communication and security layer, it looks great when running as sidecar in k8s, or each service on a separate machie.

As we are going to deliver several services within one machine, and can't deliver it within k8s, I'm not sure if we can use envoy, I didn't find any reference on using envoy in additional ways, are there additional deployment methods I can use to enjoy it?

Answer (score 2):

You can [run part of your services on Kubernetes and part on VMs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/virtual-machines/).

Comment: all the above links do not have any content anymore.

Comment: @Ganpat thank you for letting me know, I have fixed the answer.